# How to create new sheets inside a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, xlsx

I have created a json to csv converter. Now I am required to create some sub-sheets in a sheet. 
I have a main spreadsheet called hello.csv and this hello.csv must contain more than 1 spread sheet( hi, sup, good). The json has multiple tables and I want to parse those tables to new spreadsheets but all should be in the same file ie. hello.csv. I know this can be done by the `workbook` class in the `xlsx writer` module but I have already written a lot of code in using `csv module`.

How do I create subsheets using the csv module?

Comment: There is no concept of sheet with respect to a CSV file, it is just a text file that contain comma separated values. If you want multiple sheets,  you have to store your data in excel format. An excel file can store multiple CSV files as sheets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no concept of sheet with respect to a CSV file.

In other words: one CSV file has only one sheet.

Ref.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values